# Select all attributes value of -Linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<Content>
    <Field Title="123">
        <Description>...</Description>
        <Comment>...</Comment>
    </Field>
    <Field Title="654">
        <Description>....</Description>
        <Comment>...</Comment>
    </Field>
    <Field Title="789">
        <Description>...</Description>
        <Comment>...</Comment>
    </Field>
    <Field Title="210">
        <Description>...</Description>
        <Comment>...</Comment>
    </Field>    
</Content>
```

Hi, I would like to extract all field nodes attribute Title value into a list using Linq. So the list must contain "123", "654", "789", "210" can anyone give me please a solution?

I tried this:

```
var fldLst = from myEl in myXmlDoc.Root.Descendants() 
         where myEl.Name.LocalName 
         select (string)myEl.Attribute("title");
```

where myXmlDoc is the XML document.

Comment: Welcome.  Your question is essentially a _set of requirements_.  [ask]

Comment: Please show what you have tried, explain what isn't working and what you have tried so to solve it

Comment: I tried this:
var fldLst = from myEl in myXmlDoc.Root.Descendants()
             where myEl.Name.LocalName
             select (string)myEl.Attribute("title");
where myXmlDoc is the XML document.

Comment: Hi @TTORNADE, I suggest you to add the code you posted in your comment to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Descendants` and `Attribute` methods:

```
var result= doc.Descendants("Field").Select(e=>(string)e.Attribute("Title")).ToList();
```